# References links have question marks

Tags: bibliographies

I am working on the bibliography of my thesis document and I am using XeTex and JabRef.When I compile the code, I get a question mark in place of the hyperlink even after compiling the code twice.I have added the below 2 packages to the class file:

```
\RequirePackage{natbib}
\RequirePackage{cite}
```

In the main .tex file, before the end document I have placed the following 2 commands:

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{thesis}
```

I am using texmaker as the editor. The .bib file in jabref contains the following code:

```
@Article{einstein,
  Title                    = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}.        ({German})
 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
  Author                   = {Albert Einstein},
  Journal                  = {Annalen der Physik},
  Year                     = {1905},
  Number                   = {10},
  Pages                    = {891--921},
  Volume                   = {322},

  Doi                      = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004}
}
```

I am not sure if I am making a mistake in including the bib file or in compiling the code. Please let me know what other information I should provide to help find a solution to this problem.

A minimum working code for this is :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\title{test}
\author{test}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents{}

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\bibliography{thesis}
\section{Author's Message}

Howdy! This is my honor to organize the LATEX Thesis Template

\section{Reference usage and example}
This subsection test the usage of Reference. Paper \cite{einstein} is referred in this way.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you run bibtex?

Comment: @Bernard Yes I ran XeLaTex 1st and then BibTex and then again XeLatex again.

Comment: Also I'm not sure a blank line in a .bib file does no harm. Otherwise a minimal code  showing the problem would be helpful.

Comment: You don't need the bib file, you need the bbl file.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Can I create that bbl file with Jabref? And how can I include that file in my document?

Comment: @Bernard I have added a sample code.. Hope that helps

Comment: did the bibtex run create a `.bbl` file?  that's the file that latex will be looking for.  if bibtex didn't create it (using the data in the `.bib` file), then something else is wrong.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I do see a 1 KB bbl file in the folder if that is what you are talking about.

Comment: Don't load both `cite` and `natbib`. Load one or the other citation managment package, but not both.

Comment: @Mico I removed natbib. I then ran Xelatex first, then bibtex and then Xelatex again. I still get a question mark instead of a reference

Comment: take a look in the `.bbl` file.  each `\bibitem` will have a label as the first element.  now match up these labels with the labels used with `\cite` in your document.  if there's any `\cite` that isn't matched, then that reference is either missing from your `.bib` file, or the label is spelled differently from what's intended.  missing labels should be reported as warnings in your log file.

Comment: @barbarabeeton the bbl file has just begin{the bibliography} and \end{bibliography} and no items between them. Also once I run Bibtex from texmaker, the code starts throwing 2 errors. The 1st is ! LaTeX Error: Environment thebibliography undefined . The 2nd one is ! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{thebibliography}.

Comment: you need to get the bib items into the `.bbl` file.  add `\nocite{*}` to your main tex file; that should put all the items in the `.bib` file into the `.bbl` file.  however, the fact that the `.bbl` file was empty means that none of your `\cite` labels matched anything in the `.bib` file.  do check that.  you should also put back the `natbib` package.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I don't know why, but now my bbl file is also not generating..

Answer (score 1):

You forgot in your post to load `hyperref` (load it as a the last package, as a general rule – though there are some exceptions). This codes runs fine with me:

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{thesis.bib}
    @Article{einstein,
    Title = {{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
    [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]},
    Author = {Albert Einstein},
    Journal = {Annalen der Physik},
    Year = {1905},
    Number = {10},
    Pages = {891--921},
    Volume = {322},
    Doi = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004}
    }
    \end{filecontents}
    \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
    \begin{document}
    \title{test}
    \author{test}
    \maketitle

    \tableofcontents{}

    \listoffigures

    \listoftables

    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{thesis}
    \newpage
    \section{Author's Message}

    Howdy! This is my honor to organize the LATEX Thesis Template

    \section{Reference usage and example}
    This subsection test the usage of Reference. Paper \cite{einstein} is referred in this way.

    \end{document}
```

[image]